# Force graphviz to preserve node positions

Tags: nodes, graphviz, sticky

I have a graph that changes over time (normally, new nodes are added). I need to regenerate the graph several times, and want all of the nodes to stick where they have been. This partially works when using graphviz with the `fdp`-algorithm, setting the `pin`-flag and specifying the positions with the `pos`-argument.

In most cases, this works pretty well. But especially when new nodes are added, the layout sometimes changes drastically - which I need to avoid. Is there an option to actually **force** these pinned positions? It could result in an ugly graph, that would be alright - but they just need to stick.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Graphviz doesn't make it easy to keep noes in the same position:

- Adding/removing a node can cause a completely different layout.
- Adding/removing a node can change the dimension of the bounding box to change.

The following works if all nodes are known when creating the graphs:

- Create a graph containing **all** possible nodes, and let graphviz lay it out. You may add `nodes[pin=true];` at the beginning of the graph (then you won't have to add it later).
- Layout the graph:

  ```
  fdp -Tdot input.gv -o input.pos.gv
  ```

  You now have a dot file containing all the nodes. You can use this as the base file for all the graphs to be created:
- For every graph, create a copy of `input.pos.gv` and hide the unneeded nodes and edges by adding `style=invis` to their attributes. This makes sure they're not displayed, but also, the place they use in the layout will not be *cropped* away (for example if at the very top of the graph).
- Lay them out using something like this (`neato` and option `-n2` being the important parts):

  ```
  neato -n2 -Tpng input.pos.v1.gv -o output.v1.png
  ```

---

Example:

input.gv:

```
digraph g{
    node[pin=true];
    a -> b;
    a -> c;
    b -> d;
    b -> e;
    b -> f;
    c -> g;
}
```

input.pos.modified.gv:

```
digraph g {
    node [label="\N", pin=true];
    graph [bb="0,0,187,207"];
    a [pos="60.846,70.555", width="0.75", height="0.5", style=invis];
    b [pos="94.351,128.04", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
    c [pos="76.868,18.459", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
    d [pos="119.08,188.8", width="0.75", height="0.5",style=invis];
    e [pos="157.97,106.75", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
    f [pos="27.319,158.05", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
    g [pos="160.1,20.585", width="0.75", height="0.5"];
    a -> b [pos="e,84.434,111.03 70.717,87.493 73.42,92.13 76.411,97.263 79.332,102.27", style=invis];
    a -> c [pos="e,71.34,36.433 66.27,52.918 66.934,50.759 67.624,48.514 68.32,46.252", style=invis];
    b -> d [pos="e,111.86,171.05 101.5,145.62 103.54,150.61 105.8,156.17 108.01,161.59", style=invis];
    b -> e [pos="e,133.72,114.86 118.76,119.87 120.45,119.31 122.17,118.73 123.89,118.16"];
    b -> f [pos="e,49.99,147.9 71.657,138.2 67.726,139.96 63.572,141.82 59.447,143.67"];
    c -> g [pos="e,133.07,19.895 104.12,19.155 110.07,19.307 116.47,19.471 122.74,19.631"];
}
```

input.png without modifications:

[image: output.png]

hidden nodes:

[image: output with invisible nodes]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, I do not know all nodes right at the start. Some background info: I'm visualizing a physical network, which can change at any time (new, previously unknown nodes are added, connections change, …). And since the end-user can move nodes around and create his own layout, it should not change completely once an update is performed. So this can't be accomplished with graphviz? And if not, is there an alternative? I've been searching for ages...

Comment: I was also thinking of creating subgraphs or creating separate graphs and combining them. Would that be a possibility? I do not have the demand that the new nodes fit in nicely...they can be positioned outside of all the existing nodes and the connections can overlap, if they need to.

Comment: Using `pin` and `pos`, you may try by adding a default (or random) `pos`  values for a new node. I think I remember having read somewhere that in order to have fixed node positions, all nodes _must_ have a `pos` attribute (don't know about the edges).