# Use current node positions and add new nodes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I (as many others, e.g. [Force graphviz to preserve node positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775844/force-graphviz-to-preserve-node-positions)  ) need to add new nodes to a graph, leaving the nodes already present unchanged.

Do you know if this could work?

1) I let graphviz draw the first instance of the graph

2) I ask graphviz to report where it placed every node

3) I add some additional nodes, using the coordinates obtained at step 2) as `pos` option, leaving just the new nodes without a `pos` attribute, free to be placed where graphviz desires.

Is it possible, or graphviz needs every position set?

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same question as the one you linked to?

Comment: what I wanted to know (and I didnt want to hijack the original question) was if I could use GV to tell me the positions, and re-use them: this way I avoid completely to personally set the positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pos` attribute is only usefule when using `neato` or `fdp` - from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dpos):

> In neato and fdp, pos can be used to set the initial position of a node.

For neato, typically the `-n` option is needed to make use of the `pos` values - from [this page](http://www.graphviz.org/content/command-line-invocation#dn) :

> If set, neato assumes nodes have already been positioned and **all** nodes have a pos attribute giving the positions.

Therefore, this isn't possible. The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16780227/63733) may prove helpful in case you can start with the full graph and hide nodes instead of adding new ones.

Comment: In my case too this is unfortunately not possible - I dont know them in advance - so I will have to set the pos manually

Answer (score 3):

mmmm, on second thought I tried it this way:

```
fdp -Tdot dir.dot -o dir.gv
```

Now dir.gv contains the `pos` info for all the nodes; then I used dir.gv to produce the 1st graph:

```
fdp -Tpng dir.gv -o dir1.png
```

I then edited dir.gv, adding a single node (without `pos` attribute), then:

```
fdp -Tpng dir.gv -o dir2.png
```

by comparing dir1.png and dir2.png, I see that the 2nd layout is completely unchanged, apart from the new node - that's what I wanted!

(edit)
well, more or less: if I start from this:
[image: step1]

and add a single node, it's rather ok:
[image: step2]

... but adding a small new cluster of nodes, they end up rather dispersed:
[image: step3]